# Async callback needs to be called several times - how to do it?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, sinon

I have a class `MyEventListener` with a method like this:

```
  onChange(inputId = 1, handler: (status) => void): void {
    this.subscribeEvent('my event', (data) => {
          handler(data);
        }
      }
    });
```

I need to stub its behavior with sinon.

So I use yieldsAsync like so:

```
   const stub = sandbox.stub(MyEventListener.prototype, 'onChange')
   stub.yieldsAsync(anObject)
```

this works fine for the first event.

Then I need another event and I call another time:

```
   stub.yieldsAsync(anObject)
```

Now this time the event does not trigger, the handler is not called.

Is it normal? Any idea what is wrong with this?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What're your tests look like? show the code.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `yieldsAsync` and not `yields`?